# Proving the characteristic function involving sequence of 2 iid variables

Tags: probability, characteristic-function

We have an iid sequence with: $X_1,X_2,...$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

We have another similar sequence: $$Y_1,Y_2,...$$.

We have a sequence $U1,U_2,...$ where, $U_n=1/\sqrt(2(n\sigma^2))(\Sigma X_j-\Sigma Y_j)$

We also have

$$W_n=1/\sqrt(n\sigma^2)(\Sigma X_j-n\mu)$$

and

$$Z_n=1/\sqrt(n\sigma^2)(\Sigma Y_j-n\mu)$$

How do we show that $\psi(U_n)(\theta)=\psi_(W_n)(\theta/\sqrt2).\psi_(Z_n)(-\theta/\sqrt2) $

ie the characteristic function of $U_n(\theta)$ evaluated at theta is equal to the product of the characteristic functions of $W_n$ and $Z_n$ evaluated at theta over root 2 and minus theta over root two repectively?

This question is about proving the characteristic function of $U_n$ can be shown as a product of the characteristic functions of $W_n$ and $Z_n$.

**Approach so far:**

I started trying to derive the characteristic function of Un by doing this:

$$ ψ_(U_n ) (θ)=E[e^iθX ]=∫e^iθx U_n dx =E cos⁡θX+iE sin⁡θX$$

$$=∫cos⁡θx  U_n dx+i∫sin⁡θx  U_n dx$$

$$=∫cos⁡θx  1/(√(2nσ^2 )  ) (∑X_j-∑Y_j )dx + i∫sin⁡θx 1/(√(2nσ^2 )  ) (∑X_j-∑Y_j)dx
$$

But then i got stuck trying to integrate the sigmas. I also doubted that this was the correct approach given that this is a sequence of variables we are talking about.

Comment: For the same reasons given in comments to your other question about $U_n,$ you haven't any hope of demonstrating this because it's not true.  Let's therefore deal with that question before posting more questions that need identical analyses.

Comment: The 2 questions i asked involve the same sequence of random variables, but the questions are different. This one is about proving that the characteristic function of $U_n$ can be written as a product of two others. I've corrected the errors in the definition of $U_n$.

Comment: Yes, the questions are different, but the answers are essentially the same: they require that you first correct the same error in the question statements so that they can be answerable, which you now appear to have done (thank you).  Why don't you wait on the present question until you have resolved the other one?

Comment: Ok - I didn't realise the answers are essentially the same. Thank you.